# Sencha change Ext.Panel title dynamically

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, panel, title, sencha-touch-2

How can I change listpanel title dynamically?
I have a navigationview where listpanel is the item. So the navigation bar display the panel title that i would change dynamically.

image:
[image: http://postimage.org/image/evxdv8fh9/]

Thanks.

```
listpanel = new Ext.Panel({
                       layout: 'fit',   
                       id:'listpanel',
                       title:'change this title dinamically',
                       items: [
                               {
                                   xtype: 'titlebar',
                                   id: 'myTitle',
                                   docked: 'top',
                                   title: 'title1'
                               },
                               { xtype: 'titlebar',
                                   id: 'myMeanConsumption',
                                   docked: 'bottom',
                                   title: 'title2'
                               },
                                   list
                               ]
                   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this,

```
Ext.getCmp('myTitle').setTitle('Changed Title');
```

---

**EDIT :**

`title` property is not available on `Ext.Panel` component. Hence, the below line is redundant.

```
title:'change this title dinamically',
```

You need to change the `title` of `titlebar` only which I already mentioned above.

I cannot see the `listpanel` title.

[image]

Comment: It says me that object has no method settitle

Comment: I ha ve TO change listpanel title

Comment: `Ext.getCmp('myTitle')` will get you the `titlebar` component. Applying `setTitle()` on it will change the title of `titlebar`. Where are you facing problem?

Comment: I would change the panel title not the titlebar title...is it possible?

Comment: Why you want to change the panel title? You titlebar title will be the title that you will see on your view top. Is it not so?

Comment: Where are you seeing the listpanel title? Check my edited post. Can you please also post your o/p screenshot?

Comment: mmm the problem is that the panel is nested in a navigationview and it displays the titlepanel....

Answer (score 0):

Add this after the listpanel is created:

```
listpanel.onAfter('painted', function () { 
listpanel.getNavigationBar().setTitle(newTitle); },  listpanel, { delay: 100 });
```